# Context menu is cut in some situations in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-3.5, contextmenu

Context menu is truncated in different .NET Framework. See images inside ZIP file (there are two screenshots, one from XP and other from Win7).

I created a simple Visual Studio 2010 solution which repro my issue.

( http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?doq7gsh75qgvzwq ).

On XP it seems to work fine, but not on Windows 7.

The issue can be reproduced on Windows 7 if target .NET Framework is 3.5 (including SP1) (please see the image from zip).

If I change the target framework to 4.0 it works fine also on Windows 7.

Is a solution to make context menu full visible in .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 7 OS ?

Comment: Nobody ? Please, I need help :)

Comment: Curious behavior... it really happens as you say. Curiously for me it happens the most if running inside Visual Studio. Still it happens SOMETIMES when VS is not running. For me this is a good candidate for Connect.

Comment: Unable to reproduce.  Possibly because I have .Net 4.5 installed?

Comment: Unable ? Please set .NET Framework 3.5 in project target framework and try again. Only in Windows 7. Not XP.

Comment: Yes I had target framework set to 3.5, running on Windows 7.

Comment: I cannot reproduce on my machine. Have you tried changing windows themes and checking what happens. Could be a problem with the template for the current theme.

Comment: Yes, I changed to basic theme but same problem. But changing theme is not workaround.

Comment: Yes its not a work around. The aim of the suggestion was to find the root cause of the problem. Once you know the problem finding a solution will be easy.

Comment: Have you SP1 for VS2010 installed? It works perfectly on my Win7/x64

Comment: With maximized window ? Try with modified-size window ! There is the problem !

Comment: Win7 64, 3.5 and VS SP1 works fine too - non-reproducible

Comment: Try to resize window and reproduce

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that when the `ContextMenu` is loaded the `ScrollContentPresenter` for the menu isn't sized correctly, clipping the `ItemPresenter` of the `MenuItem`s (Below is an abridged version of the visual tree showing the issue).

```
PopupRoot, Acutal Width: 219,027, Desired Width: 219,027
    Decorator, Acutal Width: 219,027, Desired Width: 219,027
        NonLogicalAdornerDecorator, Acutal Width: 219,027, Desired Width: 219,027
            ContextMenuProxy, Acutal Width: 219,027, Desired Width: 219,027
                SystemDropShadowChrome, Acutal Width: 214,027, Desired Width: 219,027
                    Border, Acutal Width: 214,027, Desired Width: 214,027
                        Grid, Acutal Width: 212,027, Desired Width: 212,027
                            Rectangle, Acutal Width: 28,000, Desired Width: 32,000
                            Rectangle, Acutal Width: 1,000, Desired Width: 31,000
                            Rectangle, Acutal Width: 1,000, Desired Width: 32,000
                            ScrollViewer, Acutal Width: 210,027, Desired Width: 212,027
                                Grid, Acutal Width: 210,027, Desired Width: 210,027
                                    Border, Acutal Width: 210,027, Desired Width: 210,027
                                        ScrollContentPresenter, Acutal Width: 210,027, Desired Width: 210,027
                                            ItemsPresenter, Acutal Width: 241,047, Desired Width: 245,047
```

Invalidating the measure of the of the `ContextMenu`'s visual root (the `PopupRoot`) when the menu is loaded should cause the layout to be updated to display the correct bounds for the `ItemsPresenter`.

The handler for the  menu's Load event:

```
private void mainMenu_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender != null)
    {
        ContextMenu menu = sender as ContextMenu;
        if (menu != null)
        {
           // get the visual root for the context menu
           var root = (FrameworkElement)GetVisualTreeRoot(menu);

           // invalidate the menu's layout
           root.InvalidateMeasure();
        }             
    }
}
```

GetVisualTreeRoot method:

```
private DependencyObject GetVisualTreeRoot(DependencyObject control)
{
    DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(control);
    if (parent != null)
    {
        return GetVisualTreeRoot(parent);
    }
    else
    {
        return control;
    }
}
```

Comment: I awarded you because this is a good workaround. I will try in few days if something works. If yes, the answer will be marked as accepted. Thank you for patience.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround:

```
<ContextMenu x:Name="mainMenu" Width="300" >
```

It seems to stop bothering when setting a fixed width.
Still a good candidate for Connect.

Comment: This is not a solution. What happens if I insert long words ?

Comment: Yes... it is not. It's a workaround. As it seems to be an incorrect behavior and need fixing from MS, all you might get are workarounds :o)

Comment: Of course, you can also limit the size of menu items so they have to wrap the text inside.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to reproduce this issue in .Net 4.5.1 also.
Not able to solve using above marked solution as well. InvalidateMeasure still results in
empty context menu sometimes and it starts appearing. When I snoop the context menu, 
found out that menu ItemsPanel size calculation is done fine, but ScrollContentPresenter size is 0.Anyone facing similar issues.
My workaround is :

```
    private static void ContextMenuOnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        var menu = (ContextMenu)sender;
        if (menu.HasItems)
        {
            menu.MinHeight = menu.Items.Count * 25;
        }

        menu.Loaded -= ContextMenuOnLoaded;
    }
```

Not sure if it is the best solution. But why does it happen is also surprising.