# WPF SpellCheck context menu in WinForms won't extend past control

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, .net-4.0

So I have an odd issue while trying to use a WPF TextBox with SpellCheck enabled inside a Winforms form, using the custom control defined in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024798/trying-to-use-the-c-sharp-spellcheck-class/4026132#4026132).
This works just fine, I've tried using it in my own sandbox project and it looks great. The problem is when I try to replace the Winforms TextBoxes inside one of our existing forms. The SpellCheck context menu is "trapped" inside the control, so all I can see are the up/down arrows of the menu. 
[image]
I'm not too familiar with Winforms, as I mostly work with WPF, so I'm having a hard time determining the problem. The text box shown above is the custom control as mentioned in the linked post. The control is contained in a forms TableLayoutPanel. How can I get the context menu to expand and actually be visible?

**Edit**

 First, to clarify, the context menu appears normally when displayed in a console application that opens the form. I did a little more testing and created a new web project (what the original problem project is) with a button that opens the form, and *then* the problem behavior occurs. What difference between the console application and the web application would cause this? 

**Edit 2**
I tried the suggestions in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412747/context-menu-is-cut-in-some-situations-in-wpf), thinking maybe the context menu really was just being automatically sized incorrectly (to fit the parent control). But none of those solutions seemed to make any difference either. 

**Edit 3**
After using snoop to look at the differences between the working context menu (windows application) and the not-working one (xbap) the only difference I could see was that the DesiredSize of the xbap instance's context menu has a smaller size, I just have no idea why.

Answer (score -1):

The wpf control is a control which is *hosted in winforms* via the [ElementHost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx).

Hence it lives **within** the area provided by the parent.

The only way is to expand it, is to change the size of the parent. Give it a try by creating a winform supersized textbox as a quick debug example. Note whether the size change works on not. If it does can the GUI accommodate that change? I can't answer that.

Comment: This is what I had originally thought was the problem at first. The weird thing is that, after some more testing, this behavior does not occur if I just run a console application that opens the form. The context menu will open as normal. However, once I created a new xbap project and opened the form from that, is when the context menu becomes limited by the control.